# faster mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a faster way to do this?

```
$data1 = mysql_query(
 "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id='$id' AND type='$type'"
) or die(mysql_error()); 

$num_results = mysql_num_rows($data1); 
$data2 = mysql_query(
 "SELECT sum(type) as total_type FROM table1 WHERE id='$id' AND type='$type'"
) or die(mysql_error()); 

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data2 )){
    $count = $info['total_type'];
} 
$total = number_format(($count/$num_results), 2, ',', ' ');
echo $total;
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_results, SUM(type) AS total_type FROM table1
    WHERE id = $id and type = $type
```

This single query will produce a one-row result set with both values that you want.

Note that you should use a parameterized query instead of direct variable substitution to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Also, I'm guessing that SUM(type) isn't what you really want to do, since you could calculate it as (num_results * $type) without the second query.

Comment: This is what I'm after thank you, could you specify the parameterized query issue please?

Comment: If, for instance, the $type field comes from user input and the user were to type "13; DELETE FROM Users" in that field, you can see what would happen.  By specifying the query with parameters (something like WHERE ID = @id AND type = @type, but it depends on your database library) and then binding properly typed values to the parameters you are safe against this kind of attack.

Comment: He would get an error, but nothing would be deleted. mysql_query() will not execute more than one query.

Comment: @Dan: Obviously, I'm not a php expert.  Is mysql_query injection-proof?

Comment: You can still alter the query in malicious ways (set $type to "something OR 1=1"?), you just can't inject a second query to run.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your queries, I think you're looking for something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(type) / COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In general: `SELECT *` can be 'shortened' to e.g. `SELECT COUNT(*)`, if all you care about is the number of matching rows.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` is slightly better (since it doesn't rely on the field data, as it is for `COUNT(id)`)

Comment: No way to JOIN the two queries then?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data1 = mysql_query("SELECT sum(type) as total_type,count(*) as num_rows FROM table1 WHERE id='$id' AND type='$type'"
) or die(mysql_error()); 
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data1 );
$count = $info['total_type'];
$num_results = $info['num_rows'];
$total = ($count/$num_results); 
echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

One line:

```
echo number_format(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(type) / COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHRE id = $id AND type = '$type'"), 0), 2, ',', ' ');
```